# MYSQL TRIGGER AFTER DELET - delete data from multiple tables

Tags: mysql

I would like to delete data in multiple tables, from a trigger but it seem like my syntax is incorrect.

```
{    DELIMITER $$
     CREATE TRIGGER `delete_store`
     AFTER DELETE ON `menufacture`
     FOR EACH ROW
   BEGIN
      DELETE FROM company WHERE OLD.id = menufacture_id ; 
      DELETE FROM product WHERE OLD.id = product.menufacture_id;
      DELETE FROM menufacture WHERE OLD.id = menufacture.parent ; 
   END $$`
}
```

> #1442- can't update table 'menufacture' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function /trigger

Comment: *but it seem like my syntax is incorrect ...* where? I don't see anything.

Comment: sorry sir can u see now this

Comment: what error you are getting?

Comment: Data does not delete from mother table

Comment: It show on database    "#1442- can't update table 'menufacture' in stored function/trigger because it is already used by statement which invoked this stored function /trigger"

Comment: sir I want to delete data from 5-6 table by using AFTER DELETE TRIGGER but...all time I'm failed so what can I do .Please give a TRIGGER QUERY for this problem ......................